# Existe alguma função para reindexar um array multidimensional?

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional, índices

Galera, to precisando de uma ajuda, tenho uma função que retorna o seguinte array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => valor1 
        [2] => valor2 
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => valor3
        [1] => valor4 
        [3] => valor5
    )
)
```

E preciso transformar nisso:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => valor1
        [1] => valor2
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => valor3
        [1] => valor4
        [2] => valor5
    )
)
```

Eu vi no stack NA que um cara resolveu o problema utilizando essa função:

```
var_dump(
    array_map(
        create_function('$x','$k = key($x);
            return (is_numeric($k)) ? array_values($x) : $x;'
        ),$aDiff
   )
);
```

[Aonde encontrei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091824/how-can-i-reindex-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Só que eu não entendi muito bem aonde substituir os valores...

Qualquer ajuda será bem vinda!

Comment: Lembre sempre de deixar seu código indentado. Para isso, utilizo "4 espaços" ou clique no botão `{ }` e então após isso indente o restante.

Comment: O problema do código postado e agora revisado vai além de mera indentação. O que foi postado foi a saída de um print_r() ao invés de um var_export() que teria produzido um código trabalhável. Não que tenha sido difícil de converter pra testar, claro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sua dificuldade, como de muitos, é entender a sintaxe cabeluda de [create_function()](http://www.php.net/create_function). Felizmente a criação de funções anônimas foi drasticamente melhorada com [Closures](http://www.php.net/Closures), mas isso é outra história.

Para reindexar um array, basta passá-lo por [array_values()](http://www.php.net/array_values), como demonstrado pelo Antony mas, se você comparar a implementação que você encontrou com a dele verá que não é necessário iterar.

Se o objetivo é mapear o array de entrada de uma coisa (índices bagunçados) para outra (organizados), basta usar [array_map()](http://www.php.net/array_map) e resolver tudo com meia linha:

```
$array = array_map( 'array_values', $array );
```

Comment: É a tipica linha que vira um helper `array_reset_keys` :)

Comment: Eu tenho [uma classe](https://github.com/nextframework/next/blob/dev/Components/Utils/ArrayUtils.php) cheia deles. Cada vez que eu tropeço num problema específico ou numa otimização eu penduro naquela classe. Digo, por enquanto né, porque a intenção é "factorizar" (digo, de *factory*) cada recurso para poder [Prototipá-los](https://github.com/nextframework/next/blob/dev/Components/Prototype.php) num *strong scalar typing*

Comment: Vlw Bruno! Eu nunca entendi muito bem quais as utilizaçoes do array_map, agora ja sei uma delas!

Comment: As funções do PHP, na maioria das vezes, são auto-explicativas. array_map(), como o nome sugere, mapeia um array. Mapear um array é transformar seus índices e/ou valores de alguma coisa para alguma outra coisa.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a função [array_values](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php):

```
for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){
    $array[$i] = array_values($array[$i]);  
}
```

[Aqui](http://ideone.com/uZUvq7) tem um teste dele funcionando.

Comment: Essa implementação não funciona pois o contador da iteração é seqüencial e crescente, mas num array bagunçado o valor corrente da iteração pode não existir.

Comment: Eu tinha tentado antes desse jeito, mas não deu certo...